# How to trace the activities or tasks launched by me is in forground or not in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am writing an Android service to monitor the user to check if that user left the activities or applications (and their child activities) launched by the service. I tried to use Activitymanager.getRunningTasks() to get the package name and task ID of the foreground activity and check if it is the same package that my service launched. This method works if all the child activities are stay in the same task.

However, if some activities in external applications is launched as a new task, then the above method is not working.

Is there something like "task stacks" or "application stacks" for me to trace if the foreground activity is launched by me or my child activities?

The code I tried so far, periodicCheck() is called periodically:

```
int myTaskId = -1;
String myPackageName = "application.launched.by.me";

void periodicCheck() {
    android.app.ActivityManager activityManager = (android.app.ActivityManager) SystemManagerService.this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<android.app.ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(10);

    String currentApplicationPackageName = taskInfo.get(0).baseActivity.getPackageName();
    int currentApplicationTaskId = taskInfo.get(0).id;
    if (currentApplicationPackageName.equals(myPackageName) || myTaskId == currentApplicationTaskId) {
        // user is staying in our target application
        // update the task ID
        myTaskId = currentApplicationTaskId;
    } else {
        // user has left our target application, do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have written so far.